# When we Seed a database in ASP.NET MVC, why do we use a lamba expression for returning the id of elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In all the examples I see, such as

```
protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
{
    context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
        new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Jane Austen" },
        new Author() { Id = 2, Name = "Charles Dickens" },
        new Author() { Id = 3, Name = "Miguel de Cervantes" }
        );

    context.Books.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
        new Book() { Id = 1, Title = "Pride and Prejudice", Year = 1813, AuthorId = 1, 
            Price = 9.99M, Genre = "Comedy of manners" },
        new Book() { Id = 2, Title = "Northanger Abbey", Year = 1817, AuthorId = 1, 
            Price = 12.95M, Genre = "Gothic parody" },
        new Book() { Id = 3, Title = "David Copperfield", Year = 1850, AuthorId = 2, 
            Price = 15, Genre = "Bildungsroman" },
        new Book() { Id = 4, Title = "Don Quixote", Year = 1617, AuthorId = 3, 
            Price = 8.95M, Genre = "Picaresque" }
        );
}
```

from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3), I see that there is a lamba expression as the first parameter of the `AddOrUpdate` and it's always shown as the `Id` (primary key?) of the table. Can someone explain what that lamba expression is for? Is it for checking whether the `Id` is `null`? I'm confused.

Comment: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to define which property should be checked to see if the `Seed()`-method should `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. In this case, if the given ID is already in the database, it will not insert it again (but update the existing entry).

But you could also check on `Title`, `Year`, ... or other properties to define if the entry should be inserted or updated in your database. Basically it's to prevent duplicates in your database, but you can give meaning to what a duplicate is to you.